# Transferring private Gitlab repos to Github?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I am a part of a design team at school and currently we use gitlab because of the free private repositories. We are looking into transferring over to a github organization because members would like their commit history to be linked with their github account.

If I were to transfer our gitlab repos to github, is there anyway that all the commits could be linked to the original programmers github account?

Comment: Just push all branches to new repo. Commits will be paired by email account, so make sure your colleagues have the same email on gitlab ang github. Or use [GitHub Importer](https://help.github.com/articles/updating-commit-author-attribution-with-github-importer/) where you can customize author attribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the email address, which was used to commit, is also configured in the Github account, this should happen automatically.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response